# If a ball were to roll through a loop, would the normal force change when compared to a frictionless block?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

I am currently working through the following problem:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Reaching part c), we are required to repeat the former parts using a spherical mass instead of a frictionless cube. I have no problems with the question itsself, however repeating part b) for the sphere I came across something I don't fully understand:

**How does the rotation of the mass affect the normal force?** I can't see how there would be any difference from a frictionless block (ie, my answer in part B), and to answer part A for the sphere I assumed there was no change in normal force. However, I'm not sure if that assumtion is true, hence the question. If my assumption does turn out to be false, I'd also like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption was correct. The net force causing rotation on a rotating ball, considered as a whole, is zero since rotation does not cause the center of mass to accelerate. Therefore, no force of rotation will effect the balance between gravity and the normal force.